# Expo TaskManager API: Updating state outside "export default"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm creating an app that tracks the current location of the user and sends the data to the server every 5 secs. I'm using expo and there's an API called `TaskManager` that needs to initialize outside the scope. Is there an alternative way to update the state outside the "export default" without using redux?.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)


  }

  state = {
    mapRegion: null,
    hasLocationPermissions: false,
    locationResult: null,
    marker: {
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0
    },
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
    location: null,
    errorMessage: null
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.onLoad();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //console.log(store.getState())
  }

   onLoad = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);

    if (status !== 'granted') {
      this.setState({
        locationResult: 'Permission to access location was denied',
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ hasLocationPermissions: true });
    }

    let isRegistered = await TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync(LOCATION_TRACKER)
    if (!isRegistered) console.log('yes its waiting status:'+ isRegistered);

    await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TRACKER, {
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
      timeInterval: 2500,
      distanceInterval: 0,
    })
  }

}

TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TRACKER, ({ data, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
    // Error occurred - check `error.message` for more details.
    return;
  }
  if (data) {
    const { locations } = data;
    //Right here, I need to update my state something like,

   this.setState({
     //...
   });  //but ofcourse this not gonna work


    console.log(locations)
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you find any way to update the state from the global scope?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple ways for make this works. First you can declare an global scope variable that will be storing you current location.

```
location = null;

TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TRACKER, ({ data, error }) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
        // Error occurred - check `error.message` for more details.
        return;
    }
    if (data) {
        const { locations } = data;
        location = locations;
        //Right here, I need to update my state something like,

        this.setState({
        //...
        });  //but ofcourse this not gonna work

        console.log(locations)
    }
});
```

Or and I think this is the best way is to set up an state container like redux.

You can see all the docs here https://react-redux.js.org/ then calling actions in the TaskManager you will be able to save current location and dispatching to all connected components what its your current location.

Answer (score -1):

You could use this library https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3 to emit events from the task, listened into a component.